# 二次元配列の非共通要素を取り出したい

Tags: python

python初心者です。

```
A = [['a',0],['b',1],['c',2],['d',3]]
B = [['b',1],['c',2]]
result = [['a',0],['d',3]]
```

AとBのリストの非共通要素を取り出し、resultのような結果を期待しています。

以下のようなプログラムを考えてみたのですが、二次元配列であるために動きませんでした。

```
result = set(A) ^ set(B)
```

変更すべき点をご教示お願い致します。

Comment: set を使う場合は `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, A)) ^ set(map(tuple, B))))` となるかと。

Comment: mapとはどのような時に使うものなのでしょうか？検索して説明を読んでもいまいち掴めませんでした。簡単に教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 例えば `map(tuple, A)` は `[tuple(v) for v in A]`(list comprehension)と同等になります。list comprehension でも良いのですが、この場合は `tuple()` 関数のみの適用になるので記述量の少ない `map` の方を選んだ次第です。

Comment: `[x for x in A if x not in B]` ではいかんの？

Comment: `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, A)) ^ set(map(tuple, B))))` == `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, B)) ^ set(map(tuple, A))))` だけど `[x for x in A if x not in B]` == `[x for x in B if x not in A]` とは限らないので、一々考える必要があるのは嬉しくない。

Comment: そうね。どちらかというとmutable vs immutableが問題の本質かも。